# Trying to run alphanet, getting error when make build-deps

Tags: node, alphanet, error

I'm trying to get a node running on alphanet. I am following the documentation here: http://tezos.gitlab.io/master/introduction/howtoget.html

When I run make build-deps, everything goes well except these two lines:

```
[ERROR] The compilation of mtime failed at "/home/username/.opam/opam-init/hooks/sandbox.sh build ocaml pkg/pkg.ml build --pinned false --with-js_of_ocaml true".

[ERROR] The compilation of ptime failed at "/home/username/.opam/opam-init/hooks/sandbox.sh build ocaml pkg/pkg.ml build --pinned false --with-js_of_ocaml true".
```

What kind of problems would this cause and does this need to be fixed before I proceed?

EDIT: Adding more information about the error.

```
#=== ERROR while compiling ptime.0.8.4 ========================================#
# context     2.0.1 | linux/x86_64 | ocaml-base-compiler.4.07.1 | git+https://gitlab.com/tezos/opam-repository.git#ebc2de016e52e8b77f250df174512a793b2fb0e5
# path        ~/tezos/_opam/.opam-switch/build/ptime.0.8.4
# command     ~/.opam/opam-init/hooks/sandbox.sh build ocaml pkg/pkg.ml build --pinned false --with-js_of_ocaml true
# exit-code   1
# env-file    ~/.opam/log/ptime-32735-d682c6.env
# output-file ~/.opam/log/ptime-32735-d682c6.out
### output ###
# pkg.ml: [ERROR] cmd ['ocamlbuild' '-use-ocamlfind' '-classic-display' '-j' '4' '-tag' 'debug'
# [...]
#      'src-os/ptime_clock.cmxa' 'src-os/ptime_clock.cma'
#      'src-os/ptime_clock.cmx' 'src-os/ptime_clock.cmi'
#      'src-os/ptime_clock.mli' 'src-os/dllptime_clock_stubs.so'
#      'src-os/libptime_clock_stubs.a' 'src-os/ptime_clock_top.a'
#      'src-os/ptime_clock_top.cmxs' 'src-os/ptime_clock_top.cmxa'
#      'src-os/ptime_clock_top.cma' 'src-os/ptime_clock_top.cmx'
#      'src-jsoo/ptime_clock.a' 'src-jsoo/ptime_clock.cmxs'
#      'src-jsoo/ptime_clock.cmxa' 'src-jsoo/ptime_clock.cma'
#      'src-jsoo/ptime_clock.cmx' 'src-jsoo/ptime_clock.cmi'
#      'src-jsoo/ptime_clock.mli' 'test-os/min_clock_os.ml'
#      'test-jsoo/min_clock_jsoo.ml' 'test-jsoo/min_clock_jsoo.html']: exited with 10


#=== ERROR while compiling mtime.1.1.0 ========================================#
# context     2.0.1 | linux/x86_64 | ocaml-base-compiler.4.07.1 | git+https://gitlab.com/tezos/opam-repository.git#ebc2de016e52e8b77f250df174512a793b2fb0e5
# path        ~/tezos/_opam/.opam-switch/build/mtime.1.1.0
# command     ~/.opam/opam-init/hooks/sandbox.sh build ocaml pkg/pkg.ml build --pinned false --with-js_of_ocaml true
# exit-code   1
# env-file    ~/.opam/log/mtime-32735-4197d2.env
# output-file ~/.opam/log/mtime-32735-4197d2.out
### output ###
# pkg.ml: [ERROR] cmd ['ocamlbuild' '-use-ocamlfind' '-classic-display' '-j' '4' '-tag' 'debug'
# [...]
#      'src/mtime_top.a' 'src/mtime_top.cmxs' 'src/mtime_top.cmxa'
#      'src/mtime_top.cma' 'src/mtime_top.cmx' 'src/mtime_top_init.ml'
#      'src-os/mtime_clock.a' 'src-os/mtime_clock.cmxs'
#      'src-os/mtime_clock.cmxa' 'src-os/mtime_clock.cma'
#      'src-os/mtime_clock.cmx' 'src-os/mtime_clock.cmi'
#      'src-os/mtime_clock.mli' 'src-os/dllmtime_clock_stubs.so'
#      'src-os/libmtime_clock_stubs.a' 'src-jsoo/mtime_clock.a'
#      'src-jsoo/mtime_clock.cmxs' 'src-jsoo/mtime_clock.cmxa'
#      'src-jsoo/mtime_clock.cma' 'src-jsoo/mtime_clock.cmx'
#      'src-jsoo/mtime_clock.cmi' 'src-jsoo/mtime_clock.mli'
#      'test-os/min_os.ml']: exited with 10
```